# Insert new records with several ids from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, which has 9 records with id = 1 - 9 (for example, there can be more than 20 ids).

I have one varchar value = 'premium'.

I need to insert these values to another table, after this action I should have 9 records with id from the first table and 'premium' varchar in the second table:

```
1, 'premium';
2, 'premium';
etc.
```

How to write the function for SQL?

Comment: Quite confusing. can you please share some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `insert . . . select` or `create table as`?

```
insert into table2 (id, value)
    select id, 'premium'
    from table1;
```

or:

```
create table table2 as
     select id, 'premium' as value
     from table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5328653aecf98924e523f20d2ac843bf)

```
INSERT INTO second_table (id, text_value)
SELECT id, 'premium' 
FROM first_table;
```